# sequence limits proof by definition

Tags: limits

If I have $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to +\infty} a(x)=5 $. and $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to +\infty} b(x)=+\infty $.
How can I prove that $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to +\infty} (a*b)= +\infty $ by definition.

Can I just put n1 for the first sequence and n2 for the second and say n0 = max (n1, n2) and that applies to all members?

Comment: by $\displaystyle\lim a_{x \to +\infty}=5 $ you mean $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to +\infty} a(x)=5 $ ? And $(a*b)$ is the product of functions or the convolution ?

Comment: Yes I didn't know how to write it down

Answer (score 2):

Since $\lim_{x \to \infty} a(x) = 5$ and $\lim_{x \to \infty} b(x) = +\infty$, there is $K_1 >0$ such that $x > K_1$ implies $a(x) > 1$ and $x > K_2$ implies $b(x) > 0$. Therefore, for $x > \max\{K_1, K_2\}$,
$$b(x) < a(x)b(x).$$
Try to conclude from that.

Answer (score 2):

By definition: $$\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n=\infty \Longleftrightarrow \forall M\in\mathbb{R} \ \exists n(M)\in\mathbb{N} \text{ such that } b_n>M \  \ \ \forall n\geq n(M) \\ \lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=5 \Longleftrightarrow \forall \epsilon\in\mathbb{R}^+ \ \exists n(\epsilon)\in\mathbb{N} \text{ such that } 5-\epsilon<a_n<5+\epsilon \ \ \ \forall n\geq n(\epsilon)$$
Then set $\epsilon:=4$. We can choose $n(4)\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $a_n>1=5-\epsilon$ for all $n\geq n(4)$. Also, for every $M\in\mathbb{R}$ we can choose $n(M)\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $b_n>M$ for all $n\geq n(M)$. Then, choosing $n\geq \max\{n(4),n(M)\}$, we have that: $$b_n\cdot a_n>M\cdot 1=M$$
Which is the definition of $\lim_{n\to\infty} b_n\cdot a_n=\infty$.

Comment: It's completely arbitrary. In fact we only need $a_n\geq k$ where $k>0$, in order to ensure that $a_n$ will be far enough from $0$, so the product $a_n\cdot b_n$ actually diverges to $+\infty$. Choose whatever $\epsilon\in\mathbb{R}^+$ such that $5-\epsilon>0$, and $a_n>5-\epsilon>0$ for all $n\geq n(\epsilon)$, and do the same argument I did.